# get time from places local time

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I am currently using

```
SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
```

to get the time of a place, which obviously returning the time in devices's current location, not of the location searched.

Is there any (easy) way to change the behaviour and get the time as the local time of the location searched?

Comment: Not sure that this help. But from what I try. I must change timezone instead of locale to get the preferred time that I want.

Comment: Ofcourse I want to change the timezone....the question is how?

Comment: Please try code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm")
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+7:00")
```

And when you want to format it just use.

```
formatter.format(Date())
```

Comment: Hi, actually that is the problem. The timezone is for the location searched, as stated. So that is a variable, not a fixed value.